# Unable to deploy web Application on embedded jetty server on equinox osgi container

Tags: web, server, jetty

I have osgi bundle which starts a embedded jetty server.

Requirement: need to a deploy a angular based webapplication on this running jetty server and should be able to open the index.html(welcome page).

Bundle setup:

Bundle.jar contains:
- META-INF
.MANIFEST.MF
- com
. java classes
- webapp
. index.html
. WEB-INF
. web.xml
- webdefault
. webdefault.xml

code inside the bundle to start the server and deploy web application

```
    QueuedThreadPool guiCallQueue = new QueuedThreadPool();
    guiCallQueue.setName("gui");

    // Server instance for Web GUI.
    myHttpServerGui = new JettyServer(guiCallQueue);

    // Create web GUI connector
    myGuiConnector = new ServerConnector(myHttpServerGui, sslContextFactory);
    myGuiConnector.setPort(GUI_HTTPS_PORT);
    myHttpServerGui.setConnectors(new Connector[]
    {
            myGuiConnector
    });

    // Create web context handler
    myRootHandlerGui = new WebAppContext();
    myRootHandlerGui.setContextPath("/test");
    myRootHandlerGui.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{new WebInfConfiguration()});
  
    URL theFavIconURL = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(JettyHttpServer.class).getResource("./webapp");
    
    myRootHandlerGui.setWar(theFavIconURL);
  
    File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/webdefault").getPath());
    URL theFavIconURL1 = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(JettyHttpServer.class).getResource("/webdefault");
  
    myRootHandlerGui.setDefaultsDescriptor(theFavIconURL1);

    MimeTypes mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();
    mimeTypes.addMimeMapping("text/html", "text/html");
    myRootHandlerGui.setMimeTypes(mimeTypes);
    myHttpServerGui.setHandler(myRootHandlerGui);
```